# checked radio button styling

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button

I am having some trouble with the styling of a checked radio button, my code generaly works, except for when there is a DEFAULT checked radio button, then the styling no longer works until I check a different radio button. My question is how can I have the same styling applied to a radio button when checked by default and is it possible to do it with CSS only?

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="accessOptions"> 
    <div class="option">
        <input type='radio' id="1"  name='11' checked='checked' class="highlight"/>
        <label for 1>Open to Anyone</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="2" name="11" />
        <label for 2>Only to Allowed Senders</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.highlight {
     background: #5479ab;
 }
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
            $this.closest('.accessOptions').find('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
         $this.closest('.option').addClass('highlight');
     });
 });
```

link to jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/priswiz/BMB9R/

Comment: Side note: It should be `<label for="1">` and not `<label for 1>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to simply add the class `highlight` to the `div` that contains the radio that is selected by default. Since your JS removes the class once another radio is selected, this should work just fine. Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w4UDz/1/

```
<div class="accessOptions"> 
    <div class="option highlight">
        <input type='radio' id="1"  name='11' checked='checked'/>
        <label for="1">Open to Anyone</label>
    </div>
    <div class="option">
        <input type="radio" id="2" name="11" />
        <label for="2">Only to Allowed Senders</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS3's `:checked` selector.

```
.highlight:checked {
    background: #5479ab;
}
```

No scripting required.

---

**Edit:**

Given the details I didn't catch during my first answer, here's how you can apply the styles to the parent `div` of the `radio` in question:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('input:radio.highlight:checked').parent(".option").addClass("highlight");

    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
            $this.closest('.accessOptions').find('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
         $this.closest('.option').addClass('highlight');
     });
 });
```

Comment: +! for simplest solutions

Comment: Holy crap, I get an exclamation point? That's way better than a vote. @php_nub_qq

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the code on the pre-checked element

so add `.filter(':checked').change();` to your code..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('.accessOptions').find('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        $this.closest('.option').addClass('highlight');
    }).filter(':checked').change();
});
```

---

The other issue is that in your HTML you applied the class to the wrong element..

If you are to mimic what your code does, you should add the `.highlight` class to the `div` and not the `input` like this

```
<div class="option highlight">
    <input type='radio' id="1"  name='11' checked='checked' />
    <label for 1>Open to Anyone</label>
</div>
```

at least that is what your code does..